# Getting Conditional Data Using PyEZ Tables

Tags: python, pyez

I'm trying to create a custom table/view for Junos interfaces. Yes, I know it already exists as a built-in/default table but this is a learning exercise that I plan to expand on later.

The problem is that I want to only grab the **inet** family address, so that is the **ifa-local** only if the **address-family** stanza includes **address-family/address-family-name** of **inet**.

Is there a way to do this from within my view YAML, or do I have to grab all address-family stanzas with my view and programmatically only keep the **inet** stanza in my python script? And how would that work?

Here is the XML structure (with unimportant bits removed for clarity):

```
<rpc-reply xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/15.1F6/junos">
    <interface-information xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/15.1F6/junos-interface" junos:style="normal">
        <physical-interface>
            <name>ge-0/0/9</name>
            <logical-interface>
                <name>ge-0/0/9.0</name>
                <address-family>
                    <address-family-name>inet</address-family-name>
                    <mtu>3986</mtu>
                    <route-table>0</route-table>
                    <interface-address>
                        <ifa-destination>10.0.2.88/30</ifa-destination>
                        <ifa-local>10.0.2.89</ifa-local>
                        <ifa-broadcast>10.0.2.91</ifa-broadcast>
                    </interface-address>
                </address-family>
                <address-family>
                    <address-family-name>iso</address-family-name>
                    <mtu>3983</mtu>
                    <route-table>0</route-table>
                </address-family>
            </logical-interface>
        </physical-interface>
    </interface-information>
</rpc-reply>
```

This is my YAML:

```
JunosDCDiscoveryInterfaces:
    rpc: get-interface-information
    item: physical-interface/logical-interface
    key: name
    view: JunosDCDiscoveryInterfacesView

JunosDCDiscoveryInterfacesView:
    fields:
        name: name
        description: description
        active: { if-config-flags/iff-up : flag }
        # ipv4_address only if address-family/address-family-name is 'inet'
        ipv4_address: {address-family/interface-address/ifa-local}
```

Finally, this is the python code I'd be using to display each interface on the router:

```
logical_interfaces = JunosDCDiscoveryInterfaces(client.device).get()
for logical_interface in logical_interfaces:
    print(f'{logical_interface.name} {logical_interface.active} {logical_interface.description} {logical_interface.ipv4_address}')
```

Comment: Can you check using item xpath something like  
item: physical-interface/logical-interface/address-family/address-family-name[text()="inet"]/parent::*/parent::*